# Objective measures in Factor Analysis

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, survey, confirmatory-factor, measurement

I am considering developing a questionnaire (to be validated) whose scales could include both self-reported subjective measures and objective measurements. Does it make sense to use factor analysis to examine both subjective and objective measurements for a questionnaire?

Most example papers I have found focus on identifying the most relevant (subjective) factors in questionnaires. Others make references to the potential inclusion of objective measures, but I have not been able to find a definitive answer.

This questionnaire (or checklist) would be an attempt to assess the "equivalency" between two artefacts. It would include subjective measures (say, from 1 to 7, how visually similar they appear to you) and objective (if you use them both to perform the same task, what's the average time difference on n repetitions?).

Does this make sense, or would it be better to focus only on subjective measures?

Comment: Nothing in the statistical setup of factor analysis (FA) makes objective and subjective measures essentially different. Whether you really need FA to asses the "equivalence" you're interested in is another matter. This is not what FA does. So I'm not quite sure what you want to make of the results of the FA, which may have implications on whether "mixing" objective and subjective measures will give you what you want to find out. (Even though there is no statistical reason against mixing, there may be reasons in terms of the kind of interpretation you'd want to give the results.)

Comment: The FA would be used to identify which of the factors have the most relevance. There would be many such measures, and as I understand it, the FA can be used to understand whether the variables are interrelated and can be described by other main or potentially unobserved variables.

Comment: That's fair enough. But how would you then use the factors to assess the equivalence you are interested in? Note that if you want to use FA to reduce the dimensionality of the feature space, you can basically decide whether you do this for subjective and objective factors together or whether you separate them. That's not a statistical decision, rather an interpretative one (for example if you want to make statements at the end about the similarity or difference between the information you get from subjective and objective factors).

Comment: I was thinking that the subjective and objective metrics would lead to either an aggregate score (or two separate ones, as you say). Some of the questionnaires I have seen just sum the scores of the different scales. Are there other approaches for this?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a single factor will do. Also I'm not sure how "equivalence" is operationalised given one, two, or more factors. (If you add questions to the original one, better write them down in the original question rather than discussing them personally with me - I may not have much more to say.)